# save image in database from session in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I am working in multistep form to submit data to database as well image,But i am stuck ,
View:

```
 <?php
    echo $this->Form->file('File',array(
    'placeholder'=>'Upload Profile',
    'accept'=>''
    ))
?>
```

Here is Controller code after user completed All step:

```
<?php

if (!empty($currentSessionData['Post']['File']) &&
    is_uploaded_file($currentSessionData['Post']['File']['tmp_name'])) {

    $fileData = fread(fopen($currentSessionData['Post']['File']['tmp_name'], "r"),
        $currentSessionData['Post']['File']['size']);
    $this->request->data[$table_name]['image_name'] = $currentSessionData['Post']['File']['name'];
    $this->request->data[$table_name]['image_type'] = $currentSessionData['Post']['File']['type'];
    $this->request->data[$table_name]['image_size'] = $currentSessionData['Post']['File']['size'];
    $this->request->data[$table_name]['image_data'] = $fileData;

}
```

i am getting input using Post Model and saving data to other table which i have loaded using loadModel() method in cakephp.
Now here $currentSessionData is Session data where i am saving user's data of all step once user completed all steps then it comes to the save part in controller.
And $tablename is new table in phpmyadmin where i want to save image_name,type,size and data.
Now proble is is_uploaded_file() method is returning false ?
$currentSessionData returns :

```
'File' => array(
    'name' => 'anonymous.png',
    'type' => 'image/png',
    'tmp_name' => 'C:\wamp\tmp\php2D7E.tmp',
    'error' => (int) 0,
    'size' => (int) 983
),
```

anonymous.png is selected file.

Any Help please I'm Stuck? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with `is_uploaded_file(realpath($currentSessionData['Post']['File']['tmp_name']))`

Comment: Does not work. Still returns false on debug.

Comment: Is the file present on the disk when you are checking with `is_uploaded_file` (exact name/path, case sensitive)? Try a `file_exists` on the file, right before or after `is_uploaded_file`.

Comment: ohhh, file dost not exist,

Comment: why is this happing .. coz i've uploaded the file?

Comment: probably this is because i'm saving the file in session ?

Comment: When is the image uploaded? At the last step? If not, the temp file will cease to exist after the end of the script execution. What I mean by that is that if the image is uploaded at step one, the tmp file will not be present at step two